# Segmentation fault (core dumped) when creating new processes

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

Firstly as the other question I posted was a lil shady I asked for that thread to be removed and kinda want to replace it with this one...

I can start by explaining what my program is supposed to do:
the program should create several processes running printenv, grep [inputarray], sort, less and then these should use pipes to transfer the data like this:
printenv -> pipe1 -> grep -> pipe2 -> sort -> pipe3 -> less -> stdout

Now I've done this recursively by calling the function "createProcesswithPipe".. 
I believe the theory behind the program is correct..

Now if you were to look at the code you'll see that

```
printf("point: %d" , pointer);
```

prints out the pointer's value every time the function is entered.. Now the problem is that it is NEVER printed out if the program is run as is. Any idea?

But if I were to remove the recursive call further down:

```
createProcesswithPipe(++pointer, executes, execute);
```

the program prints out "point: 0" before getting the same error: Segmentation fault(core dumped)

Also don't mind the comments in swedish! And if you got any questions ask away! I'm kinda lost :)

```
/* digenv.c - dig (ta reda på) env (enviroment variablar) */
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define PIPE_READ_SIDE ( 0 )
#define PIPE_WRITE_SIDE ( 1 )

pid_t childpid; /* för child-processens PID vid fork() */


void createProcesswithPipe(int pointer, int executes, char* execute[])
{
    printf("point: %d" , pointer);

    int pipe_filedesc[ 2 ]; /* för fildeskriptorer från pipe(2) */
    int return_value; /* för returvärden från systemanrop */

    return_value = pipe( pipe_filedesc ); /* skapa en pipe */
    if( -1 == return_value ) {perror( "Cannot create pipe" ); exit( 1 );} /* om pipe()     misslyckades */

    childpid = fork(); /* skapa första child-processen */

    if( 0 == childpid )
    {
        return_value = dup2( pipe_filedesc[ PIPE_READ_SIDE], STDIN_FILENO );
        if( -1 == return_value){perror( "Cannot dup" ); exit( 1 );}

        /* TA BORT GAMLA REFERENSEN TILL PIPE BEHÖVER INTE HA 2st!!!!!!! */
        return_value = close( pipe_filedesc[PIPE_READ_SIDE] );
        if( -1 == return_value ){perror( "Cannot close read end" ); exit( 1 );}

        /* THIS PIPE SHOULD ONLY READ */
        return_value = close( pipe_filedesc[PIPE_WRITE_SIDE] );
        if( -1 == return_value ){perror( "Cannot close write end" ); exit( 1 );}

        if(pointer <= 3){
            createProcesswithPipe(++pointer, executes, execute);
        }
        else if(3 == pointer && executes < 4){
            return_value = dup2( STDOUT_FILENO, pipe_filedesc[ PIPE_WRITE_SIDE] );
            if( -1 == return_value){perror( "Cannot dup" ); exit( 1 );}

            /* TA BORT GAMLA REFERENSEN TILL PIPE BEHÖVER INTE HA 2st!!!!!!! */
            return_value = close( pipe_filedesc[ PIPE_WRITE_SIDE ] );
            if( -1 == return_value ){perror( "Cannot close read end" ); exit( 1 );}

            (void) execlp( execute[executes], execute[executes], (char *) 0 );
        }
        else
        {
            return_value = dup2( STDOUT_FILENO, pipe_filedesc[ PIPE_WRITE_SIDE] );
            if( -1 == return_value){perror( "Cannot dup" ); exit( 1 );}

            /* TA BORT GAMLA REFERENSEN TILL PIPE BEHÖVER INTE HA 2st!!!!!!! */
            return_value = close( pipe_filedesc[ PIPE_WRITE_SIDE ] );
            if( -1 == return_value ){perror( "Cannot close read end" ); exit( 1 );}

            char* execute2[executes-4];
            int i;
            for(i = 1;i<executes-4;i++){
                execute2[i] = execute[i+3];
            }
            (void) execlp( execute[executes], execute[executes], (char *) execute2 );
        }
    }
    else
    {

        if( -1 == childpid ){   perror( "Cannot fork()" );  exit( 1 );}  /* fork() misslyckades */

        return_value = dup2( pipe_filedesc[ PIPE_WRITE_SIDE], STDOUT_FILENO );
        if( -1 == return_value){perror( "Cannot dup" ); exit( 1 );}

        /* Kommer vi hit i koden så är vi i parent-processen
         och fork() har fungerat bra. */

        /* THIS PIPE SHOULD ONLY WRITE */
        return_value = close( pipe_filedesc[ PIPE_READ_SIDE ] );
        if( -1 == return_value ){perror( "Cannot close read end" ); exit( 1 );}

        /* TA BORT GAMLA REFERENSEN TILL PIPE BEHÖVER INTE HA 2st!!!!!!! */
        return_value = close( pipe_filedesc[ PIPE_WRITE_SIDE ] );
        if( -1 == return_value ){perror( "Cannot close read end" ); exit( 1 );}

        (void) execlp( execute[executes], execute[executes], (char *) 0 );

        /* exec returnerar bara om något fel har uppstått
         och om exec returnerar så är returvärdet alltid -1 */
        perror( "Cannot exec &execute[executes]" );
        exit( 1 );

    }
}




int main( int argc, char * argv[] )
{
    char* execute[3+argc-1];

    execute[0] = "printenv";
    execute[3+argc-3] = "sort";
    execute[3+argc-2] = "less";

    int i;
    for(i = 3;i<(3+argc-1);i++)
    {
        if(!(strcmp(argv[i-3], "more"))){
            execute[3+argc-2] = "more";
        }
        else{
            execute[i] = argv[i-3];
        }
    }

    createProcesswithPipe(0, (3+argc-1), execute);

    exit( 0 ); /* Avsluta parent-processen på normalt sätt */
}
```

Comment: Try changing `printf("point: %d" , pointer);` to `printf("point: %d\n" , pointer);`. The extra `\n` (newline) should flush cause the buffer to flush. (My guess is that it's crashing before the buffer is flushed.)

Comment: Amazing that helped quite a lot :)

Now it prints:
Point: 0
Point: 1
Point: 2
Point: 3
Point: 4
Actually it's not a pointer it's an int called pointer cause I'm from java and that's how I do it :P

Comment: You should use a debugger, relying only on printfs for debug is a lot harder.

Comment: Like @Étienne said, you should really use a debugger for this. I was just trying to quickly address why you weren't getting any output. Assuming you're using `gcc`, if you run your program through `gdb`, you can use the `backtrace` command to find out exactly which line the SEGFAULT is coming from, inspect the stack, etc. [CMU has a simple gdb tutorial](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~gilpin/tutorial/) that you could look at. You could also probably find one in Swedish.